# Why DKOM rootkit does not crash system or scheduler

Tags: windows, kernel, rootkit

DKOM (Direct kernel object manipulation) rootkits can hide a process by changing the process list in the kernel. Why doesn't crash the system. Shouldn't scheduler be effected by this?